# Can HorizontalScrollView be disable on touchevent and accessible using button

Tags: android, button, touch-event, horizontalscrollview

Actually I am working on a code in which Scrolling can be used using left or right buttons and scrolling on touch be disabled ....I am new with android ...so no much knowledge

Answer (score 0):

You can use scrollView.scrollTo(x,y) by passing x and y position of view and disable the scrollview onTouch of view.

Comment: Use smoothScrollTo if you want the animation

Comment: Sir I have done scrolling using button ....but i am unable to disable scrollview on touch...may you share the code to disable scrollview on touch please...